# Why does mutate change the variable type?

Tags: r

```
activity <- mutate(
    activity, steps = ifelse(is.na(steps), lookup_mean(interval), steps))
```

The "steps" variable changes from an int to a list. I want it to stay an "int" so I can aggregate it (aggregate is failing because it is a list type).

Before:

```
> str(activity)
'data.frame':   17568 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ steps   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ date    : Factor w/ 61 levels "2012-10-01","2012-10-02",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ interval: int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...
```

After:

```
> str(activity)
'data.frame':   17568 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ steps   :List of 17568
  ..$ : num 1.72
  ..$ : num 1.72
```

Lookup mean is defined here:

```
lookup_mean <- function(i) {
  return filter(daily_activity_pattern, interval == 0) %>% select(steps)
}
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example? also what is lookup_mean

Comment: Your question lead me to the problem. Lookup_mean is returning a row in a dataframe, not a number as I had intended. I'll correct that and either remove this post or show how this was a conversion or casting error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that lookup_mean returns a list, so R casts each value in activity$steps to a list. lookup_mean should be:

```
lookup_mean <- function(i) {
  interval <- filter(daily_activity_pattern, interval == 0) %>% select(steps)
  return(interval$steps)
}
```